# getStaticProps not working if the page is requested from cmd (not browser)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

A Next JS page with a code like:

```
const eventPage = (props) => {
    const { event } = props
  return (
    <div> my event { event.name } </div>
  )
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [],
        fallback: true
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  console.log('getStaticProps fired...')
  const event = await request(`events/${params.id}`); 
  return {
    props: {
        event: event.data || null,
    }
  }

}

export default eventPage;
```

Returns a page with body like

**my event undefined**

if the page was requested for the FIRST time not in browser but in terminal.

As this page path is not included in `paths` and the `fallback` is `true` (in `getStaticPaths` function), the page must be generated and cached on first request.

Everything is executed as supposed to, if I run the page in browser. And also everything works fine if I use `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps`.

But if I use `getStaticProps` and get the content of the page let's say with Python:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://example.com/event/1')
with open('pageContent.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

According to saved page content, I get wrong page and I don't see "getStaticProps fired..." in npm logs.

I remarked this issue after I got empty title and description meta tags for the pages that hadn't been loaded in browser before.
I checked meta tags with websites like:
http://tools.buzzstream.com/meta-tag-extractor
https://metatags.io/

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If you have a reproduction you might want to open a Github ticket or check if some exists already. Maybe something is lacking in server requests (since they don't have host etc.), that prevents the incremental build to trigger.

Comment: Yes, I opened a bug report on Github and got answer. I should use fallback: 'blocking' )

Answer (score 1):

I opened a bug report on Github and got answer to my problem.

I should use `fallback: 'blocking'`. Like:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return { paths: [], fallback: 'blocking' };
}
```

I've checked this and it works great.

P.S. I had been investigating this issue for a few days and I don't know how I couldn't see **fallback: 'blocking'**

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-blocking

Comment: Ha right for googlers, according to the doc, `fallback: true` will return a loader and then only render the page => it rely on some JS to work. `fallback:blocking` will return directly the rendered page, but will be a bit slower